# How to find & add substring between the last two backslash?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings:

- abcd/aa546a\downloadable\\111\\
- abcd/aaa23a\downloadable\\234456\\
- abcd/bbbb13\downloadable\\999\\

how can I find the substring between the last two \ and add the substring to the add?

Result list should be, how can I get list like this?:

- abcd/aa546a\downloadable\\111\\111
- abcd/aaa23a\downloadable\\234456\\234456
- abcd/bbbb13\downloadable\\999\\999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using regexes:

```
substr = s.split(r"\\")[-2]
s += substr
```

With regexes:

```
import re
substr = re.search(r"\\\\(\d+)\\\\$", s).group(1)
s += substr
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
def u_line(s):
   return re.sub('(?<=\\\)(\d+\\\)(?=$)', '\\1\\1', s)[:-1]

print(u_line('abcd/aa546a\downloadable\\111\\'))
```

Output:

```
'abcd/aa546a\\downloadable\\111\\111'
```